# Find the max value on a tuple with its corresponding pair

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I have a long Python tuple where I'd like to find the largest value. I have some numerical values and their probabilities, The tuple sample is like this:

```
(array([ 5,  5,  3, ..., -1, -4, --5]), array([ 0.25,  0.75,  0.8, ...0.05, 0.2, 0.6])
```

What I want is to be able to extract the largest probability but get the corresponding numerical value to it (X), to basically create a new tuple. Something like this based on the numbers above:

```
> Max tuple: ([3,0.8])
```

I have done soemthing like this
`new_tuple = max(map(max, tuple_list))[1]` for example, but it just gives me the highest probability and not the number it corresponds to, how can I extract the highest 2nd number (probability) to create a new tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip` the two arrays together, then pass a `key` function to `max` to pick the pair with the largest element of the second array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = (np.array([ 5,  5,  3, -1, -4, -5]), np.array([ 0.25,  0.75,  0.8, 0.05, 0.2, 0.6]))
>>> max(zip(*data), key=lambda i: i[1])
(3, 0.8)
```

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I needed, I had to use the zip function. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You can zip the two elements and get the max with a custom key.

```
>>> max(zip(*l), key=lambda x:x[1])
(3, 0.8)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
>>> tuple(np.stack(data)[:,np.argmax(data[1])])
(3.0, 0.8)
```